# How can I display all CPT of a DBN in the Bayes Net Toolbox (MATLAB - BNT)?

Tags: matlab

The following code only displays the first 2 time slices of my DBN:

```
%% Display CPT
% learnt_bnet was created using mk_dbn()
disp('CPT')
for i=1:length(learnt_bnet_obj.CPD)
    disp(['Node #' num2str(i)])
    s=struct(learnt_bnet_obj.CPD{i});
    s.CPT
end
```

How can I display all CPTs?

Comment: Isn't your DBN a HMM like a 2 TBN, where the CPT for first 2 slices are representative of the entire DBN

Comment: Yep, that was indeed the issue, I got misled by 'DBN' while in fact it is just a  2 TBN.

Answer (score 1):

In the Bayes Net Toolbox, what is called Dynamic Bayesian Network is in fact just a Temporal Bayesian Network in which we can specify a different structure for the first time-slice:

http://bnt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/usage_dbn.html :

> Note that "temporal Bayesian network" would be a better name than
>   "dynamic Bayesian network", since it is assumed that the model
>   structure does not change, but the term DBN has become entrenched. We
>   also normally assume that the parameters do not change, i.e., the
>   model is time-invariant. However, we can always add extra hidden nodes
>   to represent the current "regime", thereby creating mixtures of models
>   to capture periodic non-stationarities.
>
> [...]
>
> To specify a DBN, we need to define the intra-slice topology (within
>   a slice), the inter-slice topology (between two slices), as well as
>   the parameters for the first two slices. (Such a two-slice temporal
>   Bayes net is often called a 2TBN.)

This means a DBN in the Bayes Net Toolbox only has 2 time-slices, which explains why you only see 2 CPT in the example you gave.

Comment: Also, you may wish to highlight why you needed 'struct'. I had spent a good 10 minutes before i figured it out!

Comment: Oh yeah, right, from what I can remember `struct` was needed to bypass some privacy check, but quite frankly I never felt the need to invest time into understanding the weird object world in MATLAB :)